# How to make parent div's height same as taller absolute child div

Tags: jquery, css, absolute

There is a child div which is `position: absolute;` This child div's height is so long that the next div can't go to the bottom of that child div as there is no fixed height in the child div as well as in the parent div. So, I need to get the height automatically of child div to parent div. Here is [my fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/u9RQS/2/)

You can see at there `<div class="article"></div>` can't go to the bottom of `div.content` as `div.content` doesn't has fixed height and has a absolute child div.

If I set like this:

```
.content {
    min-height: 200px;
}
```

The problem will be solved, but, I can't do like this. There can be 10 box or 100 box at the left bar. So, I can't know the imagination height of the `div.left-bar` That's why, I've tried to set the parent's height same as the longest absolute child div's height by jQuery. But, that script has not been worked! Can you please tell me what's the correct script for it?
my not working jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var leftBarHeight = ('.left-bar').height();
   $('.content').css("height", leftBarHeight);
});
```

Comment: You're missing a $ in front of `('.left-bar')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/u9RQS/3/

```
var leftBarHeight = $('.left-bar').height();
$('.content').css("height", leftBarHeight);
```

You are just missing `$` on `('.left-bar')`